# WPF DataGrid prefill a Cell default value on edit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have very simlistic (partof) data-bound ViewModel that exposes a Nullable property, which is later rendered in a `DataGrid`:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   private DateTime? _date;
   public DateTime? Date {
     get => _date;
     set => Set(ref _date, value);
   }
}

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModels}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Everything works as expected, Dates which has a value are displayed, cells for `null` values are completely blank.
However, how can I prefill bound `null` values with `DateTime.Now` **when entering cell edit mode**? Bonus point: the `DateTime.Now` is reverted back to `null` in case cell edit was aborted.

---

**Attempt 2** (based on comments), using `DataGridTemplateColumn` and swich `TextBlock` without `TargetNullValue` for a `TextBox` with one, sadly that is not a valid binding:

> TargetNullValue '6/25/2019 0:00:00' (type 'DateTime') cannot be
>   converted for use in 'Text'

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Date" Header="Date">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Date, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}}"/>
      </DataTemplate>                            
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: so the value will be null when editing the value has to be DateTime.now if the entered DateTime is not in exact  formate it has to be null

Comment: @AvinashReddy whenever editing a `null` value, the textbox should be pre-filled with current date (as a suggested value), user is free to change the suggested value. If the entered value is not a valid datetime, what happens is not important (validation error, accept last correct input, rollback to null value, rollback to current date... etc. etc.), though rollback to null is preferred. Any non-null values should not be affected.

Comment: [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=netframework-4.8) rather than `DataGridTextColumn` would give you more options for this control.  I don't think the bare text column is going to do what you want.

Comment: @FelixCastor thanks for the suggestion, can you be more specific on what to leverage? Have explored `TargetNullValue` and `Style` options in order to provide the `DateTime.Now` values, but none seem to lead to a solution - all ended in various binding and xaml parsing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `TargetNullValue` property if you bind to the `SelectedDate` property of an invisible `DatePicker`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Date" Header="Date">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dp" SelectedDate="{Binding Date, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=dp}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The other option would be to implement a [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8) that converts `DateTime.Today` to a `string`.

> Thanks for the answer, its definitely much simpler plus it allows non-static values. However, it is not possible to accept the pre-filled DateTime.Today unless user changes it to a different date and back ...

If you want to persist the value, you should set the source property explicitly. You could do this by handling the `CellEditEnding` event. Something like this:

```
private void Dgm_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    ContentPresenter cp = e.EditingElement as ContentPresenter;
    if (cp != null)
    {
        Panel panel = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cp, 0) as Panel;
        if (panel != null)
        {
            TextBox tb = panel.Children.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (tb != null)
            {
                DateTime dt;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(tb.Text, out dt))
                {
                    e.Row.DataContext.GetType().GetProperty("Date").SetValue(e.Row.DataContext, dt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: din't think of that. Nice one

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its definitely much simpler plus it allows non-static values. However, it is not possible to accept the pre-filled `DateTime.Today` unless user changes it to a different date and back (which defeats the purpose of the pre-filling QoL improvement).

Comment: @wondra: Then you need to acually set the source property. But why don't you set it to `DateTime.Now` by default then?

Comment: @mm8 because null value has a meaning. Imagine a property 'ValidFrom' of a 'LoayltyCard' class if the property does not have a value the card is not (yet) valid. Natuarally, when you display list of such cards you want to distinguish those that were issued today and those that were never activated. As QoL improvement, since you 99.99% just put there today's date as you hand out the card, you would like to auto-fill it when you try edit it for the first time.

Comment: @wondra: You can set the source property if you handle the `CellEditEnding` event. See my edit.

Comment: Any ideas how the binding itself could be leveraged, i.e. not a hardcoded property name? I was exploring this line of solutions as well (derived DGTextColumn and set textbox.Text, it failed on converting string->DT), but it always failed on reliably setting source.

Comment: @wondra: Do you mean `(e.Column.Binding as Binding).Path.Path`?

Comment: More like `(e.Column.Binding as Binding).SetValue(DateTime.Now)`, let the framework handle all validation and conversion. But there is nothing like this as far as I know.

Comment: No, you should replace the *path*, i.e. "Date" in my sample code, with the value of `(e.Column.Binding as Binding).Path.Path`. I don't see how this is related to your original question though.

Comment: You are right, even though my intentions were as described in 'ValidFrom' example above, I did not included it unambiguously in the question body - it would be unfair to ask for the perfect write back, I can ask that one later. With this out of the way, I can accept your answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MultiDataTrigger and write the conditions if the date is equal to null and the textbox is focused we can set the value to DateTime.now

**DataGridTemplateColumn**

```
 <DataGrid Name="drg" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CanUserAddRows="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox  BorderThickness="0" >
                                <TextBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                        <Style.Resources>
                                            <Converter:DateTimeNullConverter x:Key="Time"/>
                                        </Style.Resources>
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Date}"></Setter>

                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Date}" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsKeyboardFocused}" Value="True" />
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Date,Converter={StaticResource Time}}"></Setter>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBox.Style>

                            </TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**Convertor**

class DateTimeNullConverter : IValueConverter
    {

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but even though the converter returns DateTime.Now, it does not seem to have any effect - nothing gets displayed in the edit.

Comment: @wondra 1. does the control goes to Converter when editing 2.Does the reaming values are displaying

Comment: Yes and yes, breakpoint is hit and DateTimes with value are displayed. My bet is on Trigger overriding value temporarily... Or sideeffects of changing it to DataTrigger (triggers in provided sample do not work).

Comment: @wondra here I updated this style which is working but note it will give the suggestion on UI but the `ItemsSource` has to be updated.

Comment: Nice, almost there - now I am trying to figgure out how to update the source - it wont get written unless the suggested datetime is edited.

Comment: @wondra For that on u need to convertor parameter to be binded link :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/456589/Bindable-Converter-Parameter

Comment: once u pass the date `MyViewModel` object u can update in the converter so the item source will be updated so when user remove the mouse the value will stay there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195520/discussion-between-wondra-and-avinash-reddy).